# Scan for all .csv in current folder and add new column to be populated later based on a previous column string

Tags: python, batch-file, extract, batch-processing

I have lots of CSV files with 3 columns where I need to add a 4th one preferably with a batch script or Powershell.

On the 4th column I should add the following string extracted between HTTPs:// and .shopdomain...

This is how it looks now when opening on a table environment:

| ID | buyer | item url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Tom | https://safariland.shopdomain.com/fghj/shoes |
| 02 | Sam | https://beastofshoes.shopdomain.com/ukgl/offers/1424 |

And how it should look after new column:

| ID | buyer | item url | shop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Tom | https://safariland.shopdomain.com/fghj/shoes | safariland |
| 02 | Sam | https://beastofshoes.shopdomain.com/ukgl/offers/1424 | beastofshoes |

The raw CSV looks as following:

```
ID,buyer,item url
01,Tom,https://safariland.shopdomain.com/fghj/shoes
02,Sam,https://beastofshoes.shopdomain.com/ukgl/offers/1424
```

At my search Info is not being as every question out there is looking for a formula where they need to sum, average or something.

Already could manage to add a new column but my needs are to cut the text between the before column, not related to sum or average or maths.

Would like a bit of light on how to achieve this if someone can help.

EDIT: Tested the Python Solution and it worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Extracting the text you want? Making a new column?

Comment: Edited the question, thanks for your help on my journey through this outstanding platform @Compo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** the url column format is uniform: Split on `'/'` and take the third item; split that on `'.'` and take the first item.

```
s = '''https://safariland.shopdomain.com/fghj/shoes'''
_,_,z,*_ = s.split('/')
whatiwant,*_ = z.split('.')
print(z)
print(whatiwant)

>>>
safariland.shopdomain.com
safariland
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory & destination directory are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o\subdir3"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.csv"') do (
 rem filename in %%G
 SET "header=Y"
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%sourcedir%\%%G") DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=2delims=/." %%q IN ("%%e") DO ECHO %%e,%%q&SET "header="
  IF DEFINED header ECHO %%e,"columnheader4"
 )
)>"%destdir%\tempfile"& MOVE /y "%destdir%\tempfile" "%sourcedir%\%%G" >NUL
GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Assuming your .csv files have a header line and each data line follows the pattern you indicate, comma-separated (raw data for testing, please) then

The `dir` finds all of the .csv files in the directory. `header` is set to `y` to indicate that a header line is expected, and then each line of the specified file is assigned to `%%e` in turn. the next `for` then analyses the line in `%%e` and sets `%%q` to the string after the `//` and before the `.` (assuming that `/` and `.` only occur in column3). The `echo` will only be executed if `%%q` is assigned, so not on header line(s), and `header` will be set to *nothing* and become undefined.

If no data line has been found, then the line must be a header, so output that line with the fourth column header.

Finally, the data is gathered to a temporary file and moved over the original.

I'll say again,

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Comment: I have removed the "fluff" from your answer. If you think the question should be closed rather than answered, then maybe consider deleting your answer.